# SASS : how to add values in array?

Tags: css, sass

In my `app.scss` file, I import two files :

`@import './component/_file1.scss';` :

```
$theme-colors: (
    "color1": #fffac8,
    "color2": #0082c8,
    "color3": #000000,
);
```

`@import './component/_file2.scss';` :

```
$theme-colors: (
    "color4": #aa6e28,
    "color5": #ffd8b1,
    "color6": #46f0f0,
);
```

As you can see, these two files have a variable `$theme-colors`.

I would like the values ​​to be added to the existing ones. Currently the values ​​in `'./component/_file2.scss'` replace the values ​​in `'./component/_file1.scss'`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You may do it like this:

```
@use "sass:map";

$theme-colors: map.merge($theme-colors, (
    "color4": #aa6e28,
    ...)
);
```

Take a look at this page from [SASS Docs](https://sass-lang.com/documentation/values/maps)